# SQLite insert into table, with JSON.stringyfy. Breaks with Quoted String

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite

I am using SQLite for mobile, mostly for hybrid mobile app development.

I am storing data to in one column like this.

```
var QueryToInsert = JSON.stringify(object) // where object is defined as below

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table (id,data) VALUES ('1', " ' " + QueryToInsert + " ' " );
```

which becomes to

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table (id,data) VALUES ('1','[{"name":"Romeo","lastName":"Juliet"}]')
```

While this works , but if i have a object like this:

```
var object = {"name": "In connection with this appellative of 'Whalebone Whales' , it is of great..." }
```

**Note** the **''** in the string.

Now if I do.

```
 INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table (id,data) VALUES ('1', " ' " + JSON.stringify(object) + " ' " );
```

It gives me an error :

**`{"code":5,"message":"near \"Whalebone\": syntax error"}`**

**Solution I have tried :**

replace all the `'` with some character before making the query. It Does work, but when there is lot of data and lot of tables, replacing all `'` its a slow process.

I am looking for any solution that will help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, single quotes inside strings must be escaped by doubling them:

```
INSERT ... VALUES ('... of ''Whalebone Whales'' ...');
```

However, it would be much easier to avoid formatting problems like this by using parameters:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table (id,data) VALUES (?, ?);",
              ['1', JSON.stringify(object)],
              onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I have removed my answer :) Thank you for clarification.